# Downgrading and upgrading python libraries using conda

Tags: python, conda

I frequently install python packages using conda, sometimes that involves downgrading an existing installed package. Afterwards, I upgrade the downgraded package to latest version again.

E.g.

```
conda install -c conda-forge iris
```

downgrades numpy to 1.10.4 from 1.11.x. Later, I do `conda update numpy` to go back to `1.11.x`

Is this ok to do or can lead to subtle issues later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr;

Probably not, since numpy `1.10 -> 1.11` is not a HUGE leap.

## Recommended approach

I would advise against not letting conda match the correct versions of each package. You can get wrong results or crashes.

## Longer explanation

The recipe for `iris` was built using numpy 1.10, so if you force numpy back to 1.11, you might have problems such as:

- *crashes*: if `iris` is compiled against NumPy (using its C Api)
- *wrong results*: if `iris` uses an API of numpy changed between versions
- *python exceptions*: if `iris` uses an API of numpy in which the implementation changed between versions.

I know that recently numpy demands that **indices** of numpy arrays be **integers only**. This broke some code. I don't remember which version of numpy did that.

This is true for all packages, not only numpy. Some libraries maintain API and/or ABI compatibility between releases, others don't.

All in all, numpy has a fairly stable API. I can't really answer for its ABI, since I don't know.